# How to toggle class using jquery if else statement?

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I want to toggle class using jquery If Else statement for specified conditions.

My Html with default css `class="horizontal"`

```
<div id="foo-bar"  class="my-item horizontal"> 
</div>
```

Now How can I shuffle my css class between `horizontal` and `vertical` using jquery where `var=mayvar` as condition.

```
myvar may be layout1 or layout2.
```

for `myvar=layout1` `class="horizontal"`
and for `myvar="layout2 class="vertical"`

and how to write the jquery if there are more than two condition for more different css classes?

Comment: where is "myvar" coming from? an input?

Comment: This comes from my wordpress option setting, dont worry about it. I implemented it and successfully storing my option value in myvar which is checked with alert(myvar);

Comment: This is two questions, hence my two answers in my submission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you do not want to use the toogleClass(), here is another solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/YFBWQ/

```
$('#foo-bar')
.removeClass('horizontal vertical')
.addClass( myvar=='layout2' ? 'vertical' : 'horizontal')
```

or

```
$('#foo-bar')
.removeClass(myvar=='layout2' ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical')
.addClass(myvar=='layout2' ? 'vertical' : 'horizontal')
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the switch in [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

> A Boolean value to determine whether the class
>   should be added or removed.

```
$('#foo-bar').toggleClass('horizontal', myvar==layout1)
             .toggleClass('vertical', myvar==layout2);
```

Comment: If there are more than 2 values for "myvar" like layout1, layout2, layout3 and so on.. and different css classes relative to each myvar value,then how can we toggle the css class?

Comment: Thanks@Adenko ! your answer is looking fine but its doesn't work for me. css class is remain as it is even myvar=layout2

Comment: be aware that `myvar=layout` sets the variable, you need a boolean to switch the classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/XVRTY/1/)**

*Html*

```
<div id="foo-bar"  class="horizontal"> </div>
```

*Javascript*

```
$('#foo-bar').toggleClass('vertical');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method that does this; it even works with multiple class names separated by spaces. So toggle both of them, no matter what's the current class of the element:

```
$("#foo-bar").toggleClass("horizontal vertical");
```

Comment: Downvoter: what is wrong with this answer? can you help me improve it?

Answer (score 1):

simple case:

```
var vh = "layout1";
$('#foo-bar').addClass(function () {
    $(this).prop('class', '');
    return vh == 'layout1' ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical';
});
```

EDIT ADDED: definative simple case sets it to no classes if none match

```
var vh = "layout9";
$('#foo-bar').prop('class',function () {
    return vh == 'layout1' ? 'horizontal' : (vh == "layout2" ? 'vertical' : (vh=="layout3" ? "reddy" : ""));
});
```

more complex case:

```
var vh1 = "layout2";
var classList = $('#foo-bar').prop('class').split(/\s+/);
$('#foo-bar').addClass(function (vh1) {
    var self = this;
    $.each(classList, function (index, item) {
       //IF you want to keep one, check it here
       if (item != "keepme") {
          $(self).removeClass(item);
       }
    });
    switch (vh1) {
        case "layout1":
            return "horizontal";
        case "layout2":
            return "vertical";
        default:
            return "reddy";
    }
});
```

EDIT2: leave the classes alone if none match! (caution, replaces all classes with new set)

```
<div id="foo-bar" class='reddy3 freddy' >hi</div>
```

keep existing:

```
var vh = "nomatches";
$('#toggle').prop('class',function (i,v) {
    return vh == 'layoutA' ? 'horizontal' : (vh == "layout2" ? 'vertical' : (vh=="layout3"? "reddy":v));
});// keeps "reddy3 freddy"
```

set multiple:

```
var vh = "greenhorizontal";
$('#toggle').prop('class',function (i,v) {
    return vh == 'layout2' ? 'horizontal' : (vh == "layout2" ? 'vertical' : (vh=="greenhorizontal"? "greeny horizontal":v));
});//sets both "greeny" and "horizontal", wipes out existing
```

FYI, substitue your "myvar" for vh and vh1 for full solution

Comment: Thanks @Mark Schultheiss ! for your valuable answer.