# JQuery toggle between two classes based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two classes and I want to toggle between them when certain condition is met

```
$(this).toggleClass('one two', condition)
```

when `condition` is met I want to add `two` class, and when it is not met I want to replace it with `one`.

I know I can just use `if else` with `addClass` and `removeClass` but the question is - can I do it with `toggleClass`?

Comment: *"when `condition` is met I want to add `two` class, and when it is not met I want to replace it with `one`."* When the condition is met, if the element has the `one` class, do you want to remove it? The difference in phrasing between the two halves of your sentence make me wonder...

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/14483867/2943218

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes it is actually exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: What actually happened when you *tried*:  `$(this).toggleClass("one two", condition)`  did it do what you wanted?  What did it not do that you wanted it to do?  If you could expand provide what you want when you do it with if/else/add/remove then it would be clearer what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use chaining and `toggleClass` like so:

```
$(this).toggleClass("one", !condition).toggleClass("two", condition);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax

```
$(this).toggleClass(condition ? "one" : "two")
```

Comment: don't think this would work as it would only toggle the class that meets the condition - ie if it had the class one applied, one would not get removed it the condition met the toggle class for two.  Also it would only toggle the class - I think OP wants to add remove based on the condition, not just toggle